# Work with a list of list and make some comparisons Python

Tags: python

I don't know how compare 2 different lists of list and write what I need:
I have a list of list. I need to check 3 things.
First if the `item[1], item[2]` of `este_mes` `item` are in the list `resto` and add the complete `item` to `changes`. 
Second if the `item[1], item[2]` of `este_mes` `item` are not in the `resto`, add to `news` and for `the item[1], item[2]` of `resto` `item` are not `este_mes`, add to `lost`

```
este_mes = [
    ['1', 'A', 'a', '300'],
    ['1', 'B', 'b', '30'], 
    ['1', 'C', 'c', '100'], 
    ['1', 'D', 'd', '4500']]

resto = [
    ['2', 'A', 'a', '3'],
    ['2', 'B', 'b', '302'], 
    ['2', 'X', 'x', '98'], 
    ['2', 'Z', 'z', '276'], 
    ['3', 'A', 'a', '54'], 
    ['3', 'B', 'b', '65'], 
    ['3', 'F', 'f', '76'], 
    ['3', 'Y', 'y', '99']]

# I need something like this but I don't know how can I do it!

changes = []
news = []
lost = []

for item in este_mes:
    if item[1] and item[2] are in some item of resto:
        changes.append(item_resto)
    if item[1] and item[2] are not in some item of resto:
        news.append(item)
for item in resto:
    if item[1] and item[2] are not in item of este_mes:
        lost.append(item_resto)
```

the answers should be:

```
news = [['1', 'C', 'c', '100'],
        ['1', 'D', 'd', '4500']]
lost = [['2', 'X', 'x', '98'],
        ['2', 'Z', 'z', '276'],
        ['3', 'F', 'f', '76'],
        ['3', 'Y', 'y', '99']]
changes = [['2', 'A', 'a', '3'],
           ['2', 'B', 'b', '302'],
           ['3', 'A', 'a', '54'],
           ['3', 'B', 'b', '65']]
```

This is the answer:

```
este_mes = []
resto = []
changes = []

for item in este_mes:
    for rest in resto:
        if (item[1] == rest[1] and item[2] == rest[2]):
            rest = [rest[0]] + [item[1]] + [item[2]] + ([float(item[3]) - float(rest[3])])
            changes.append(rest)
            resto.remove(rest)
```

Comment: What is the question? What problems are you having?

Comment: I don't know how can write the lines below the # in python @wwii

Comment: In that case you should be able to make this question vastly shorter. Narrow it down to your actual problem.

Comment: Your "answer" does not produce the output that you list in your problem statement.  You've left out the arithmetic on the final field, and it fails to build the `news` list at all.

Answer (score 1):

I have commented the code so hopefully you can follow the logic.

```
#initialise our lists
news = []
changes = []
lost = []
#iterate over each list in `este_mes`
for l in este_mes:
    #matches marks whether we have matched in `resto`
    matched = False
    for ll in resto:
        if l[1] == ll[1] and l[2] == ll[2]:
            #we matched, so append list from `resto` to changes
            changes.append(ll)
            matched = True
    #if there were no matches, append the `este_mes` list to `news`
    if not matched:
        news.append(l)

#iterate over lists in `resto` to look for ones to add to `lost`
for l in resto:
    #check to see if there are any matches in `este_mes`
    for ll in este_mes:
         if l[1] == ll[1] and l[2] == ll[2]:
             break
    else:
         #this `else` clause is run if there was no `break` -
         #indicates that no matches were found so add to `lost`.
         lost.append(l)
```

which outputs the correct lists:

```
>>> news
[['1', 'C', 'c', '100'], ['1', 'D', 'd', '4500']]
>>> lost
[['2', 'X', 'x', '98'], ['2', 'Z', 'z', '276'], ['3', 'F', 'f', '76'], ['3', 'Y', 'y', '99']]
>>> changes
[['2', 'A', 'a', '3'], ['3', 'A', 'a', '54'], ['2', 'B', 'b', '302'], ['3', 'B', 'b', '65']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `any` operator to see whether there is *any* occurrence of a particular condition within a list.  In this case, I compare two-letter sequences for each new list.

For each of these, make sure to grab the item from the proper list (este_mes or resto).  That list has to be the outer `for` in the list comprehension + iterable combination.  That's why the first of these has `este` in the outer part, while the other two have `rest` in the outer part.

```
news = [este for este in este_mes 
           if not any((rest[1], rest[2]) == (este[1], este[2]) 
               for rest in resto)]

changes = [rest for rest in resto
              if any((rest[1], rest[2]) == (este[1], este[2])
                   for este in este_mes)]

lost = [rest for rest in resto
           if not any((rest[1], rest[2]) == (este[1], este[2])
                for este in este_mes)]

print(news)
print(lost)
print(changes)
```

Output:

```
[['1', 'C', 'c', '100'], ['1', 'D', 'd', '4500']]
[['2', 'A', 'a', '3'], ['2', 'B', 'b', '302'], ['3', 'A', 'a', '54'], ['3', 'B', 'b', '65']]
[['2', 'X', 'x', '98'], ['2', 'Z', 'z', '276'], ['3', 'F', 'f', '76'], ['3', 'Y', 'y', '99']]
```

Comment: I would change the condition to `any(rest[1] == este[1] and rest[2] == este[2] for rest in resto)` or possibly `(rest[1], rest[2]) == (este[1], este[2])`. Those can work with any data types and avoid problems like `'A'+'bc'=='Ab'+'c'`.

Comment: Nice idea; I spaced on the tuple technique.  Will edit the code.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell, your actual question is simply "how do I check whether something is in an item of `resto`?"

Here's a nice way:

```
def in_item(items, value):
    return any(value in item for item in items)

# For example
in_item([[1, 3], [5]], 1)
Out: True
in_item([[1, 3], [5]], 2)
Out: False
```

Then you can do `if in_item(resto, item[1]) and in_item(resto, item[2]):` and so on.

Comment: OP needs the two columns to match in the same row; your logic assumes that matching in different rows is okay.

Comment: Are you sure? I don't think it's in their description of the problem.

Comment: "if item[1] and item[2] are in some item of resto".  The `resto` item is singular.

Comment: It's ambiguous. And relying on shades of grammatical meaning from a questioner whose first sentence talks about a "list of list" is ridiculous.